# How to improve Python code for swapping bits of a 32-bit integer

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

## Swap bits - Coding interview question

A few days ago, I came across the following coding interview question (using **Python**).

#### Problem:

*Given a 32-bit integer, swap the 1st and 2nd bit, 3rd and 4th bit, up til the 31st and 32nd bit.*

*Here's some starting code and an example:*

```
def swap_bits(num):
    # Fill this in.

print(f"0b{swap_bits(0b10101010101010101010101010101010):032b}")
# 0b01010101010101010101010101010101
```

#### My Solution:

```
def swap_bits(num):
    num_out = 0
    for ii in range(16):
        num_out += (num & (2**(2*ii))) << 1
        num_out += (num & (2**(2*ii+1))) >> 1
    return num_out

print(f"0b{swap_bits(0b10101010101010101010101010101010):032b}")

# Output: 
# 0b01010101010101010101010101010101
```

#### My Question to You:

Do you have any suggestions for improvement, in terms of efficiency, length of code, readability, or whatever. I will highly appreciate your feedback. **Thanks!**

Comment: Regarding *readability* I suggest using comments and so-called function's docstrings, be aware that you should keep balance between being too wordy (like commenting every line) and too comment-shy (like not comments at all)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this (well, you **must not** use a loop for this, in a coding interview), just a couple of binary operators:

```
>>> n = 752846942
>>> bin(n)
'0b101100110111111000100001011110'
>>> bin(((n >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((n & 0x55555555) << 1))
'0b011100111011110100010010101101'
```

I added a leading 0 to the last number, to make the result more easily comparable to n.

---

What's the trick?

Consider your number as a vector of bits. Exchanging pairs of bits is equivalent to moving all even-numbered bits one position to the left, and all odd-numbered bits one position to the right (assuming bit numbering start at 0, begining with the LSB on the right).

Moving to the left and to the right is just a binary shift: `n << 1` and `n >> 1`. But if I simply do `(n << 1) | (n >> 1)`, I will move all bits, and the result will be wrong. So, first select which bits you want: the even bits are `0x55555555 & n`, the odd bits are `n & 0xaaaaaaaa`.

So a possibility is:

```
((n & 0x55555555) << 1) | ((n & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1)
```

Another way is to select bits after the shift but before the binary or:

```
((n << 1) & 0xaaaaaaaa) | ((n >> 1) & 0x55555555)
```

Since the bit parity is reversed by the shift, I just have to swap the constants 0x55555555 and 0xaaaaaaaa.

To get the same constant on both side of the binary or, I select before the shift on one side, and after on the other.

Comment: How did you get the magical `n`, if not with `int('0b1010101010101010101010101010101', 2)`? Explaining that would add some value to your answer...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Shorter than `0b010...`. Actually I computed it with `eval("0b" + "01" * 16)`. Just too lazy to type it.

Comment: Actually, I copied it from your answer, that was even easier ;) But you could probably add it as well to your answer!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You remark made me think again: I replaced it with the hex value.

Comment: That is pretty optimized, but kindly drop an explanation when you write such a compressed expression out of your pocket.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get rid of the exponentiation which is costly. It's possible to compress it more but as long as every operator is binary the complexity stays the same.

```
# to keep the code readable
def swapBits(n, p1, p2): 

    ''' Move p1'th to rightmost side '''
    bit1 = (n >> p1) & 1

    ''' Move p2'th to rightmost side '''
    bit2 = (n >> p2) & 1

    ''' XOR the two bits '''
    x = (bit1 ^ bit2) 

    ''' Put the xor bit back to their  
        original positions '''
    x = (x << p1) | (x << p2) 

    ''' XOR 'x' with the original number  
        so that thetwo sets are swapped '''
    result = n ^ x 
    return result 

n = 11
print(bin(n))
k = 0
for i in range(32):
    n = swapBits(n, k, k+1)
    k+= 2

print(n)
print(bin(n))
```

Comment: Don't use a loop. Really. It's a one liner with binary ops.

Comment: Yes, but how do you come up with such a compressed expression in 3 minutes window, I'm really curious. Can you add some explanation with your code too?

Comment: Actually it was in less than 3 minutes. You have to know your binary ops well. There are lots of tricks with them, see for instance the book [Hacker's Delight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker%27s_Delight), or [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). For this case, I remembered the trick to reverse bits ([here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel))

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's indeed helpful + your explanation now makes your expression pretty obvious. I also noticed you're big on Mathematics site so now it makes me less guilty for not thinking it before :)